# JavaScript statement shorthand needed to be expanded

Tags: javascript

I have this statement:

`pn = r.notFound == "true" ? "Not currently assigned" : "Currently assigned to VPMO " + r.currentAssignment;`

and I need to add a condition for "undefined" and then a value to it.  It basically needs to read something like…

`r.notFound == "undefined" then “Already assigned to this project”

else if 
r.notFound == “true” then “Not currently assigned”

else

“Currently assigned to VPMO “ + r.currentAssignment;`

Comment: will you ever test for any other value? (you're getting close to the threshold for a `switch`)

Comment: @shad Never say never but the choices are limited and this fix is only temporary until the update procedure is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pn;

if (r.notFound == 'undefined') { // be aware that this checks for STRING undefined
  pn = 'Already assigned to this project';
} else if (r.notFound == 'true') { // be aware that this checks for STRING true
  pn = 'Not currently assigned';
} else {
  pn = 'Currently assigned to VPMO ' + r.currentAssignment;
}
```

?

**EDIT**

If you want to check whether the variable is defined use:

```
if (typeof r.notFound === 'undefined')
```

Comment: Okay, then looking at your approach, what if the undefined is not a string, would I just remove the quotes and would I need to change the number of = (equal) signs?

Comment: Thanks.  Your solution is just cleaner than the original code I'm working with and the equals always get me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple nested ternary operator:

```
r.notFound == "undefined" ? 
    "Already assigned to this project" :
    (r.notFound == "true" ? "Not currently assigned" : "Currently assigned to VPMO " + r.currentAssignment)
```

Comment: You can do that as long as I'm not the one who has to maintain the code ;)

Comment: @fabio-cicerchia So the ? and the : work in conjuction with each other?

Comment: @PeeHaa LOL.  Personally, I like your approach better but I'm filling in for someone else and I'd like to keep the code looking like their other statements.

Comment: yes, you can nested infinite ternary operator. obviously @PeeHaa was right, the code became unmaintainable.

Comment: @dlackey: Just saying :) Use whatever code you want. I just wanted to prevent that you come over here screaming: WHY DIDN'T YOU TELL ME! ;)